# writing to a struct with a struct

Tags: c, struct, header-files, scanf

I am reading from a txt file using fscanf.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalLines; ++i)
{
    fscanf(fp,"%s %s %f %f[^\n]", &cp[i].name, &cp[i].animal, &cp[i].coordinates.lat, &cp[i].coordinates.lng);
    printf("Name: %s\nAnimal: %s\nLat: %.6f\nLong: %.6f\n\n", cp[i].name, cp[i].animal, cp[i].coordinates.lat, cp[i].coordinates.lng);  
}
```

The problem is it does not set/print the innermost structs members or variables which are 2 doubles lng and lat are not being assigned. What the best way to make this work? am I on the right track? I tried to cast it with a (double) but that through errors. any ideas?

UPDATE

I have updated the code to how it should be and im still getting a 0 value on all. any ideas why?

Comment: I have updated my code, and still no luck. It seams like the double does not want to be in there.

Comment: Show the struct declaration.

Comment: Can you see the difference between `&cp[i].name, &cp[i].animal,` and `cp[i].name, cp[i].animal,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your structure is as follows:

```
/* Structure Holding Coordinates */
typedef struct location                                                         
{                                                                               
    double lat;                                                             
    double longt;                                                           
}location_t;                                                                    


typedef struct geo                                                              
{                                                                               
    char name[64];                                                              
    char animal[64];                                                            
    location_t loc;                                                        
} geo_t;
```

---

Your Reading is to be done as follows:

```
geo_t arr[NO_ENTRIES];     /* NO_ENTRIES is total lines in file */                                                     
for(i = 0; i< NO_ENTRIES; i++)                                              
    fscanf(fp, " %s %s %lf %lf", arr[i].name, arr[i].animal, &arr[i].loc.lat, &arr[i].loc.longt);

printf("After Reading\n\n\n");                                              
for(i = 0; i< NO_ENTRIES; i++)                                              
    printf(" %s %s %f %f\n", arr[i].name, arr[i].animal, arr[i].loc.lat, arr[i].loc.longt);
```

See it here: http://ideone.com/99dmvL

Answer (score 0):

use `%f` instead `%s` for double values.

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %f %f", cp[i].name, cp[i].animal, &cp[i].coordinates.lat, &cp[i].coordinates.lng);
```

Also your printf will have an error. I suggest you do these:

```
printf("Name: %s\nAnimal: %s\nLat: %f\nLong: %f\n\n", cp[i].name, cp[i].animal, cp[i].coordinates.lat, cp[i].coordinates.lng);
```

- Don't use `"%lf"`. Your variables are doubles, so you should use `"%f"`.
- In your printf calls, if needed use a format specifier like this: `"%.5f"`. It tells printf to output 5 digits after the decimal point.

You can also refer the [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) & [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the value are still 0.0000 when i printf them.

Comment: I hope your struct declaration seems to be the issue. can you please post the struct declaration here.

Answer (score 0):

For double, use `%lf`, just like what you did in the `printf`. So change the code to:

```
fscanf(fp,"%s %s %lf %lf", cp[i].name, cp[i].animal, &cp[i].coordinates.lat, &cp[i].coordinates.lng);
```

Answer (score 0):

As u are trying to read long double values u should use %lf instead of %s where u are       scanning double values
 example : fscanf(fp,"%lf",&double_value);

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the value using the floating point control string. Not a string control string.

```
 fscanf(fp,"%s %s %lf %lf", cp[i].name, cp[i].animal, &cp[i].coordinates.lat, &cp[i].coordinates.lng);
```